# ng-repeat orderBy issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

through `ng-repeat` I want to plot videos in a defined order according to the `id` number (from 1 to 5).

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="vidObj in videoObjects | orderBy: 'id'">
        <span>{{vidObj.id}}</span>  
    </div>
</div>
```

I try to apply the filter `orderBy`, but apparently is not working properly. Do you have an idea of what I am doing wrong? This is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc16op6u/) with the complete code.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

**EDIT:** Thank you for your replies, but the `json` file can not change.

Comment: `orderBy` filter required array, and `videoObjects` is not an array so `orderBy` won't work

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a work around to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes I have modified this JSFiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/fc16op6u/33/]

Comment: Cool, but you have to fork it to make it readable

Comment: Custom filter example: http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javascript :

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.videoObjects = {
        "Frank": {
          "id": 1
        },
        "Gerard": {
          "id": 2
        },
        "Rein": {
          "id": 3
        },
        "Ida": {
          "id": 4
        },
        "Ellen": {
          "id": 5
        }
      };

 $scope.arr = Object.keys($scope.videoObjects).map(function(k) { return $scope.videoObjects[k] });
console.log($scope.arr);

    });
```

and the HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="vidObj in arr | orderBy: 'id'">
        <span>{{vidObj.id}}</span>  
    </div>
</div>
```

I updated your fiddle with this code.. It is working well.

Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/tirthrajbarot/fc16op6u/39/

Answer (score 1):

I modified your Json and it works

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.videoObjects = [
        {
            "name": "Frank",
          "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Gerard",
          "id": "2"
        },
        {
          "name": "Rein",
          "id": "3"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ida",
          "id": "4"
        },
        {
          "name": "Ellen",
          "id": "5"
        }
      ]
    });
```

Comment: What make you think that json is the problem?

Comment: The `json` file does not have to change

Comment: okey. I have created custom filter for that. Please refer above JSFiddle
[ http://jsfiddle.net/fc16op6u/38/ ]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the built-in orderBy filter works with arrays.

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) says "The collection can be an Array or array-like object (e.g. NodeList, jQuery object, TypedArray, String, etc)."

Check this example in the documentation that says "Example Ordering a table with ngRepeat".

Answer (score -2):

Try a valid json, somthing like:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.videoObjects = [
         {
          "id": 1,
          "Frank":'name'
        },
         {
          "id": 2,
          "Gerard":'name'
        }
      ];

    });
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc16op6u/37/)

Comment: I tried in the fiddle, but apparently it is not working

Comment: Can you post the fiddle?

Comment: It is in the description

Comment: Posted a update, LOL why are the down-votes, just missed his jsfiddle.

Comment: Down vote was for your original answer, something about adding ": true"  after the "orderBy: 'id'", before you completely modified it to this latest.

Comment: May have been a known issue but it didn't answer this question.  If it did, then why did you change your answer?